# Unknown task text-classification, available tasks are ['feature-extraction', 'sentiment-analysis',

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am trying to use Transformers for the first time based on this model:

https://huggingface.co/bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion?text=I+like+you.+I+love+you

The sample code provided here its:

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("text-classification",model='bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion', return_all_scores=True)
prediction = classifier("I love using transformers. The best part is wide range of support and its easy to use", )
print(prediction)
```

However I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-74ca6189abbe> in <module>
      1 from transformers import pipeline
----> 2 classifier = pipeline("text-classification",model='bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion', return_all_scores=True)
      3 prediction = classifier("I love using transformers. The best part is wide range of support and its easy to use", )
      4 print(prediction)

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py in pipeline(task, model, config, tokenizer, framework, revision, use_fast, use_auth_token, model_kwargs, **kwargs)
    340     """
    341     # Retrieve the task
--> 342     targeted_task, task_options = check_task(task)
    343 
    344     # Use default model/config/tokenizer for the task if no model is provided

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py in check_task(task)
    234         raise KeyError(f"Invalid translation task {task}, use 'translation_XX_to_YY' format")
    235 
--> 236     raise KeyError(
    237         f"Unknown task {task}, available tasks are {list(SUPPORTED_TASKS.keys()) + ['translation_XX_to_YY']}"
    238     )

KeyError: "Unknown task text-classification, available tasks are ['feature-extraction', 'sentiment-analysis', 'ner', 'question-answering', 'table-question-answering', 'fill-mask', 'summarization', 'translation', 'text2text-generation', 'text-generation', 'zero-shot-classification', 'conversational', 'translation_XX_to_YY']"
```

And Yes I Installed transfomers first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the example that you referenced from their docs is out of date. The text-classification pipeline has been renamed to sentiment-analysis, therefore you need to replace:

```
classifier = pipeline("text-classification"...
```

with:

```
classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis"...
```

Here's a [link to the pipeline docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.18.0/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TextClassificationPipeline) if you want to read more about it.